# Is MacBook Air 2017 used for programming viz Java or Python and also for Web development?

Tags: macbook-pro, unix, java, development, python

I'm planning to buy a MacBook Air 2017 8 GB RAM with 256 GB SSD. The reason I'm going with a MacBook Air is primarily for portability and Battery life, since I see that it gives at least 10 hours.

Is it good for performing the below activities? Please suggest. I have looked into MacBook Pro line as well, since, it is heavy, it would be difficult to carry around where ever i go.

**My Primary Work:**

I would like to do only programming on this laptop, by installing IntelliJ IDEA IDE, PyCharm and WebStorm etc.
I primarily work on programming languages such as Java, Python and Node.js for web development (even though am very new to web development)... I would like to run couple of containers on this device.

I forgot to mention earlier that, in INDIA, we are having a amazon sale of Air 2017, which might end soon, hence, i was interested in going only for Macbook Air and nothing else, for now.

Comment: There are for now 3 answers going roughly in the same direction. I can add that a friend of mine has a MBA for the very same usage than you and is very happy with it.

Comment: Yes that's fine but do note that Jetbrains products love RAM--- highly recommend going to 16GB RAM for IntelliJ + one or more JVM instances

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about the Air: Yes.

You may want to consider broader options as well. For MacBooks in general, the biggest advantage to doing development on a them is that you get XCode and the best possible experience when developing iPhone/iPad apps and Mac apps.

However in your case, it seems you're not doing mobile development, and price and/or weight are a concern since you're considering a MacBook Air.

if you're open to windows, take a look at something like the [HP x360 which is well reviewed](https://www.laptopmag.com/reviews/laptops/hp-spectre-x360-13-inch) and has advantages over the MacBook air:

- MBA is limited to 8 GB of RAM, while the HP allows 16 GB. This can be significant for software development.
- MBA only supports old style USB 3. The HP supports USB type C 3 .1 that can charge the laptop or drive an external monitor.
- HP has a watch band hinge that allows folding the screen back to be like the tablet. Not a big use case but actually helpful sometimes.
- MBA resolution is 1440x900, while the HP resolution is full HD 1080p.

Price and battery life are very similar between the two in a 256GB/8GB configuration.

Of course, Apple consistently has the best support and ability to use their stores.

If you have a hard requirement to stay on the Apple platform, I would suggest reconsidering the MacBook Pro 13. In general it's better suited to be a development machine, and it's really not that heavy to carry around.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I forgot to mention earlier that, in INDIA, we are having an amazon sale of Air 2017, which might end soon, hence, i was interested in going only for Macbook Air and nothing else, for now.

Answer (score 0):

As the MacBook Air is a great computer, I can say yes for your usage.

The other alternative is the MacBook Pro 13’’ without touch bar. More power, a way better screen (important when you spend hours on line codes).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I forgot to mention earlier that, in INDIA, we are having a amazon sale of Air 2017, which might end soon, hence, i was interested in going only for Macbook Air and nothing else, for now.

Answer (score 0):

I would get a MacBook over a MacBook Air if you can afford it.

- better screen
- better storage
- better CPU

The MacBook has NVMe storage which is superior to older technology in terms of iops and energy savings - for containers and dev work and compiling open source code - I’m very happy with the 2015 MacBook and the newer ones are even better. Any CPU in them is great so don’t feel you need to pay for the m7/i7 if you’d rather spend money on storage or accessories or a better display. In terms of productivity, you could program on a raspberry pi or three if you feel you need more “containers” to run. Unless I’m virtualizing something heavy like Windows - I don’t miss MacBook Pro CPU and hardware with my MacBook. That being said - the Air is also over qualified for what you describe.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I forgot to mention earlier that, in INDIA, we are having an amazon sale of Air 2017, which might end soon, hence, i was interested in going only for Macbook Air and nothing else, for now.

Comment: Anything is better than nothing so ignore the parts that are qualified by “if you can afford it”. The air is a solid machine for your needs, @forkdbloke. We don’t always “afford” the MacBook here for some of our professional workers.